# Prove that for all s ∈ Σ*, s ∈ L(MEven) implies s ∈ L(Even)

Tags: logic, formal-languages, automata

Q: Prove that for all s ∈ Σ*, s ∈ L(MEven) implies s ∈ L(Even)

Additional information:

```
The Σ is {l,r,u,d} where α ∈ Σ which denote the controllers (l = left, r = right, u = up and d = down) whilst Strings s, t, ... over Σ⋆ thus denote sequence 

of commands.

lefts is the number of transitions of l

L(Even) = { s | s ∈ Σ* and even(lefts(s))}

M(Even) is a DFSA that only accepts commands from L(Even).
```

I have managed to tackle and do the DFSA of M(Even), thanks to @rici who helped me get in the right direction.

That being said I'm once again unsure on how to go about this and would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

TIA

[Question Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqiNg.png)

Comment: What is lefts(s)? It's still unclear as in your other posts.

Comment: @Wuestenfux lefts is the number of transitions of l

Comment: You've defined M as an automaton that "only accepts commands from L(Even)". This is another way of saying that L(M) a subset of L(Even): your question answers itself. Have you perhaps made a typo somewhere?

Comment: @realdonaldtrump no not really, I attached a photo of the actual question.